# как удалять данные из бд срок которых больше недели django/python

Tags: python, django

У меня есть в модели поле с датой добавления в бд, мне надо, чтобы если прошла неделя, то все, например, статьи, которые были созданы неделю назад, удалялись автоматически

```
class Test(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   data = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

Comment: Самый простой вариант - настроить выполнение скрипта по cron

Answer (score 0):

Вам потребуется настроить систему задач, что-то [celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html)

Затем у вас есть задача, которая ежедневно запускает получение объектов с датой создания более 7 дней.

Когда у вас есть эти объекты, вы можете удалить их.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Сообщество здесь ленивое и рассчитывает получить всё и сразу. А ответы, которые подразумевают необходимость подумать лучше писать в качестве комментариев к вопросу, а не ответами)))